# Having trouble declaring a stack using the stack collection for Go

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm translating a tool originally written in C++ to Go using VS Code, but the Go linter doesn't like my stack declaration.

I've imported the stack collection per the Go documentation and I think my go workspace directory hierarchy is correct.

```
-go (workspace)
    -bin
    -pkg
        -darwin_amd64
            -github.com
                -golang-collections
                    -collections
                        -stack.a
    -src
        -github.com
            -golang-collections
                -collections
                    -stack
                        stack.go
                        stack_test.go
            -zwnewsom
                -verifier
                   main.go
```

```
package main

import (
    "C"
    "github.com/golang-collections/collections/stack"
)

type Item struct {
    key   int
    value int
    //sum   int
    sum float64

    numerator   int64
    denominator int64

    exponent float64

    status Status

    promoteItems := stack.New()
}
```

the 'New()' function should return a pointer to a stack but the VS Code Go linter gives me a yellow squiggly under ':= stack.New()' with an error saying "expected ';', found ':='" which is doubly confusing since I was under the impression that Go doesn't use semicolons to terminate lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't initialize values in the struct definition, just set the type. Initialize the value when you create a new instance of the struct.

```
type Item struct {
    key   int
    value int
    //sum   int
    sum float64

    numerator   int64
    denominator int64

    exponent float64

    status Status

    promoteItems stack.Stack
}

func main() {
    // create an instance of struct Item
    item := Item{
        promoteItems: stack.New(),
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks Matt. I ended up with 'promoteItems stack.Stack' for the declaration and that seemed to please the linter.

Comment: That sounds right, the package is imported as `stack`, so `stack.Stack` is the type.